Issue while doing actions for Ros2 using ROSLIBJS . Getting NonexistentFieldException
I am using this version of roslib [npm version]
"roslib": "github:RobotWebTools/roslibjs#ros2-actions-no-typescript"
I am using ros2 classes only provided from ros2-actionclient example
I am calling navigate_to_pose action via ROSLIB
const navigateToPose = (x, y, res) => {
  //Create an action client
  var actionClient = new ROSLIB.Action({
    ros: ros,
    name: "/navigate_to_pose",
    actionType: "nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPose",
  });

  //Goal message for navigateToPose
  var goal = new ROSLIB.ActionGoal({
    goalMessage: {
      goal: {
        // Add the goal field here
        pose: {
          header: {
            frame_id: "map",
            stamp: {
              sec: Date.now(), // You can set the actual timestamp here
              // nanosec: Date.now(), // You can set the actual timestamp here
            },
          },
          pose: {
            position: { x: x, y: y, z: 0.0 },
            orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 },
          },
        },
        behavior_tree: "",
      },
    },
  });
  console.log(goal);
  // console.log(goal.pose.pose.position);
  var goal_id = actionClient.sendGoal(
    goal,
    (result) => {
      console.log("Result for action goal:", result.result.sequence);
      res.status(200).send(result.result.sequence);
    },
    (feedback) => {
      console.log(
        "Feedback for action on " +
          actionClient.name +
          ": " +
          feedback.partial_sequence
      );
    }
  );
  console.log("Goal sent with ID: ", goal_id);
  res.send("Goal sending...");
};

Error message 
[rosbridge_websocket-1] [ERROR] [1726135110.855788579] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client 8f6b9da9-6079-4769-8370-8038de36b5b1] send_action_goal NonexistentFieldException: send_action_goal:/navigate_to_pose:4
```

